# How do I take data from one table, and overwrite it from another table, with a SELECT statement in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

Ok, let me try to explain this question...

I have two tables: `movieitems` and `movieitems_custom`. They both have identical columns of **barcode**, **title**, **runtime**, and **username**.

I want a query or stored procure that will pull from `movieitems` (to get a movie's details owned by a user) and then pull from and *overwrite* the return data from `movieitems_custom` (to get a user's custom data entry).

Note that `movieitems_custom` doesn't always have a matching entry from `movieitems`, only sometimes.

---

Here is an example:

`movieitems` for a user contains these two items for user `'joe'` that he owns:

1234 - Batman Begins - 120 minutes

1235 - 12 Monkeys - 97 minutes

and in `movieitems_custom` we could have one entry like this for `'joe'` that he customized:

1234 - Batman 1 aka Batman Begins - 120 minutes

**What I want my statement/procedure to return is this:**

1234 - Batman 1 aka Batman Begins - 120 minutes

1235 - 12 Monkeys - 97 minutes

---

Is some type of `JOIN` statement enough to make this happen, or am I looking at something more complex?

Comment: `SELECT COALESCE(movieitems_custom.name, movieitems.name) FROM movieitems LEFT JOIN movieitems_custom ON movieitems.some_id = movieitems_custom.some_id AND movieitems_custom.user = 'joe'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
    I.barcode,
    IFNULL(C.title, I.title) AS title,
    I.runtime,
    I.username
FROM
    movieitems I 
        LEFT JOIN movieitems_custom C 
        ON I.barcode = C.barcode AND I.username = C.username
```

Comment: On the `IFNULL`, do i have to do the `AS title` or will it default to `title` without it because the column names are the same?

Comment: @EthanAllen, you do need the `AS` clause - no defaults there.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use COALESCE  which you can read about here

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx

basically it will let you specify where to get the values from if any are NULL.